# Python: ModuleNotFoundError despite module being installed

Tags: python

I made a module named 'calc' and installed it using the following command in cmd:
`py -3 -m pip install calc-2.1.tar.gz`.
I can import the module and use it when I run python in cmd.
Yet, anywhere else, it doesn't work. Both IDLE and Anaconda raise ModuleNotFoundError.
The same goes for other modules I try to install.

By the way, I'm really new to python, so could you please be a bit more specific with the instructions?

Comment: Try running the python script using ```python3 file.py```. Also, install the module using ```python3 -m pip install calc-2.1.tar.gz```, that way you use the same commands. By the way, you should probably use just normal Python and pip installs rather than Anaconda, imo.

Comment: Also, are you using Git Bash?

Comment: @PeterNielsen I entered what you said in cmd, but nothing happens... and I'm not using Git Bash.

Comment: @PeterNielsen And why not Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what the problem was.
I was using different versions of python (3.7 in IDLE, 3.8 in Spyder, 3.9 in cmd) which is why the module installed by cmd didn't work other places.

Comment: FYI, if you are going to do many applications on python and want to avoid this kind of issue, you should setup something called a `virtualenv` for each application. This allows you to have different versions of python and different versions of pacakges set up for each application separately.  https://pythonbasics.org/virtualenv/